# JavaScript editor for embedding into C# program

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, textbox, editor

Into a .NET application which I am developing, I would like to embed an editor (text box) in which the user can enter and edit JavaScript code. Syntax highlighting would be great. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Ooops, is this for WinForms, WPF, Web ..?

Comment: Does not seem suitable for an open source project. It's Winforms (wpf ok as well).

Comment: Whats not suitable for an open source project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for something to use with WinForms, take a look at [ScintillaNet](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET), the .Net bindings for the great [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) editing component. Its open source and very reliable.
[image]

Comment: ScintillaNet link is bad, points to old codeplex site.  Code has moved to [github](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET)